# assigning a vector to pass as an argument in the $ index function

Tags: r, indexing

first time posting a question

My question is around debugging a problem I have using the $ index function

The below function is hopefully going to loop through a set of .csv files and combine the vectors of the "column_name" into x, where I would then get the mean of x.

```
overall_mean <- function(directory, column_name, id = ) {

  filenames <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
  x <- as.numeric()
     for (i in id) {
         data <- read.csv(filenames[i]) 
         x <- c(x, as.numeric(data$column_name)) #herein lies the problem
  }
  mean(x)
}
```

I would like to call the function as:

```
overall_mean ('the directory on my computer', emoout, 1:10)
```

When I debug the function, I can see that everything works as it should until the the      `x <- data$column_name`, where X remains null.

My exploration of the problem so far:

when I type the following

```
data$emoout
```

I get a vector of strings as expected.

when I type the following

```
column_name <- emoout
data$column_name
```

I get a null result.

Clearly its because I don't understand how the $ function works. Is there some trick to getting the $ to recognize I want to index the content of the column_name vector?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `data[[column_name]]`. You can't the `$` operator with the value of a variable, as far as I know.

See the `$` section about halfway down this page: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html